# global scope for variabile seems not functioning

Tags: php

In a custom Joomla 2.5 module i've this:

```
$username   = $params->get('username'   ,   '');
$password   = $params->get('password'   ,   '');
$url    = $params->get('url'        ,   'http://api.xxxxx.com');
```

So, i recall that variables from config.

I've written this  function:

```
function callAPI($data) {
global $username, $password, $url;
$data['username']   = $username;
$data['password']   = $password;
$data['output']     = 'XML';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$parsed_result = new SimpleXMLElement(str_replace('&','&amp;',$result));
return $parsed_result;
} // function callAPI($data)
```

And... it doesn't function.... Error is

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML
```

If manually I add $url in function... It does his job:

```
function callAPI($data) {
global $username, $password, $url;
$url = 'http://api.xxxxxx.com';
$data['username']   = $username;
$data['password']   = $password;
$data['output']     = 'XML';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$parsed_result = new SimpleXMLElement(str_replace('&','&amp;',$result));
return $parsed_result;
} // function callAPI($data)
```

Obviously I'm sure that $username and $password are filled with right value, because my webserver responds if I add $url. So i suspect that only one problem is in "url" value.

I need solve my problem. In function "callAPI" $url is blank. On first part of piece, after $params->get $url is correctly full with my url.

Thank you

Comment: What's the problem besides using globals as function params, you mean?

Comment: Not that I know anything about Joomla, but global variables are generally a bad idea, for this reason. It's likely the variable is getting modified somewhere else in your code, and you'll have to track that down.

Comment: Why ask for opinions instead of finding out for sure? :) You can test output `$username, $password, $url` to see what they contain; also curl has a `curl_error()` function that will tell you if something went wrong with the call

Comment: @Pekka $username contains correct username, $password contains my password but $url is blank (on callAPI function, on first piece of script ($params->get('url') ) is correctly valorized....

Comment: @cHao no, i would solve my problem.

Comment: Are you inside a function when setting `$url`? Because you would need to make that part global, too. And the other users are right, globals are not ideal practice - you could pass the three values as parameters to the function, for example.

Comment: @Pekka I know that i could pass like parameter, but i would learn something on more. It is strange that $url is blank, no? My code is all sequential. First of all i get parameters, second i create a function (see "global" part). After that $username and $password have their value, $url is blank :(

Comment: Maybe `$url` gets overwritten elsewhere? This has a rational explanation *somewhere*, but it's impossible to see from the code you show what happens.

Comment: No... code is made of that 4 parameters + function. On other file, there is simple print_r(callAPI); and i know that $url not rewritten. By the way, it will be a mistery for me, Swapped to previous version and i send $usernamae, $password and $url in parameters et voilà... Thak you in every case for support.